# Bound a function with parameter involving logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

In my master project I encounter the following function
$$f_\varepsilon(x) = \ln\left(\frac{x^{1 + a} + \varepsilon^\beta}{\lambda(x)^2 + \varepsilon^2}\right)$$
for $a$ close to zero, $\beta \in (1, 2)$ and
$$\lambda(x) = \frac{x}{|\ln(x)|^2}.$$
I aim to bound the following quantity
$$g_\varepsilon(x) = \bigg|\frac{1}{f_{\varepsilon}(x)} - \frac{1}{f_{0}(x)}\bigg|$$
on a certain interval $[0, x_0]$, $x_0 \ll 1$, where $f_0$ is just $f_\varepsilon$ with the parameter $\epsilon = 0$. Clearly, for $x \to 0$, we get
$$g_\varepsilon (0) = \frac{1}{(2 - \beta)|\ln \varepsilon|}$$
so I feel that we should get something like
$$g_\varepsilon(x) \le \frac{C}{(2 - \beta)|\ln \varepsilon|}$$
for $C > 0$ independent of $\varepsilon$. I tried to bound $|\ln(\varepsilon)|g_\varepsilon(x)$ by such a constant but I couldn't prove rigourously that it didn't depend on $\varepsilon$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.